# 2004 Jeep Sahara battery problems

Tags: jeep, battery-drain, wrangler

I have a 2004 jeep  Sahara and the other day I was fooling with the component that turns the flow of air in the ducts in the jeep was running fine then the next day I went to crank it and nothing just clicking and dash component flipping back and forth so tried to jump it off it would turn over but acts like it's not getting fuel so I charged the battery for a day and it turns over fine just not firing but has never done this before any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Evidently something drained the battery or the battery is failing, you can go to most any major auto parts store and have the battery tested. If it is the original battery that came with the car definitely replace it.